Blank Screen Issue on Navigate Up or Back with Hilt and Navigation Component
I am newbie and i working on an Android project using Hilt for dependency injection and the Navigation Component for navigation. I have one MainActivity as my host and two fragments: HomeFragment and DetailFragment.
The navigation flow works fine when I navigate from HomeFragment to DetailFragment. However, when I try to navigate back, the screen goes blank, and none of the fragments are displayed.
MainActivity
`@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : BaseActivity<ActivityMainBinding, MainViewModel>() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var featuresNavigation: FeaturesNavigation

    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun getVM(): MainViewModel = viewModel

    private lateinit var startDestination: Pair<Int, NavArgument?>
    override val layoutId = R.layout.activity_main

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host) as NavHostFragment
        featuresNavigation.bind(navHostFragment)

        with(intent) {
            initGraph(this)
            data = null
            replaceExtras(Bundle())
        }
    }

    private fun initGraph(intent: Intent?) {
        startDestination = createStartDestination(intent)

        if (startDestination.first == R.id.homeFragment) {
            Timber.e("MainAct test initGraph")
            featuresNavigation.setGraph(
                R.navigation.main_navigation,
                startDestination.first,
                startDestination.second
            )
        }
    }

    private fun createStartDestination(intent: Intent?): Pair<Int, NavArgument?> {
        val bundle = intent?.getBundleExtra(Constants.KeyParam.KEY_EXTRAS)

        return when (intent?.action) {

            else -> {
                R.id.homeFragment to null
            }
        }
    }
}`

ActivityMain.xml
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host"
            android:name="com.usmh.libraries.navigationcomponent.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            tools:context=".ui.activity.MainActivity" />
    </FrameLayout>

</layout>`

HomeFragment
`@AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeFragment :
    BaseFragment<FragmentHomeBinding, HomeViewModel>(R.layout.fragment_home) {

    @Inject
    lateinit var featuresNavigation: FeaturesNavigation

    private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun getVM() = viewModel


    override fun initView(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.initView(savedInstanceState)
        activity?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(null)

        featuresNavigation.openDetail()
    }
}`

DetailFragment
`@AndroidEntryPoint
class DetailFragment :
    BaseFragment<FragmentDetailBinding, DetailViewModel>(R.layout.fragment_detail) {

    @Inject
    lateinit var featuresNavigation: FeaturesNavigation

    private val viewModel: DetailViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun getVM() = viewModel


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // TODO: Use the ViewModel
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        featuresNavigation.navigateUp()
    }
}`


AppNavigatorImpl
`@ActivityScoped
class AppNavigatorImpl @Inject constructor() : BaseNavigatorImpl(), FeaturesNavigation {

    override fun openDetail(bundle: Bundle?) {
        openScreen(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_detailFragment, bundle, R.id.detailFragment)
    }
}`

FeaturesNavigation
interface FeaturesNavigation : BaseNavigator {
    fun openDetail(bundle: Bundle? = null)
}

main_navigation.xml
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.usmh.features.ui.HomeFragment"
        android:label="HomeFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_detailFragment"
            app:destination="@id/detailFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:name="com.usmh.features.ui.DetailFragment"
        android:label="DetailFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail" />
</navigation>`

NavHostFramgent
public open class NavHostFragment : Fragment(), NavHost {
    private var navHostController: NavHostController? = null
    private var isPrimaryBeforeOnCreate: Boolean? = null
    private var viewParent: View? = null

    // State that will be saved and restored
    private var graphId = 0
    private var defaultNavHost = false

    final override val navController: NavController
        get() {
            checkNotNull(navHostController) { "NavController is not available before onCreate()" }
            return navHostController as NavHostController
        }

    @CallSuper
    public override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        if (defaultNavHost) {
            parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setPrimaryNavigationFragment(this)
                .commit()
        }
    }

    @CallSuper
    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        var context = requireContext()
        navHostController = NavHostController(context)
        navHostController!!.setLifecycleOwner(this)
        while (context is ContextWrapper) {
            if (context is OnBackPressedDispatcherOwner) {
                navHostController!!.setOnBackPressedDispatcher(
                    (context as OnBackPressedDispatcherOwner).onBackPressedDispatcher
                )
                // Otherwise, caller must register a dispatcher on the controller explicitly
                // by overriding onCreateNavHostController()
                break
            }
            context = context.baseContext
        }

        navHostController!!.enableOnBackPressed(
            isPrimaryBeforeOnCreate != null && isPrimaryBeforeOnCreate as Boolean
        )
        isPrimaryBeforeOnCreate = null
        navHostController!!.setViewModelStore(viewModelStore)
        onCreateNavHostController(navHostController!!)
        var navState: Bundle? = null
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            navState = savedInstanceState.getBundle(KEY_NAV_CONTROLLER_STATE)
            if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_DEFAULT_NAV_HOST, false)) {
                defaultNavHost = true
                parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .setPrimaryNavigationFragment(this)
                    .commit()
            }
            graphId = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_GRAPH_ID)
        }
        if (navState != null) {
            // Navigation controller state overrides arguments
            navHostController!!.restoreState(navState)
        }
        if (graphId != 0) {
            // Set from onInflate()
            navHostController!!.setGraph(graphId)
        } else {
            // See if it was set by NavHostFragment.create()
            val args = arguments
            val graphId = args?.getInt(KEY_GRAPH_ID) ?: 0
            val startDestinationArgs = args?.getBundle(KEY_START_DESTINATION_ARGS)
            if (graphId != 0) {
                navHostController!!.setGraph(graphId, startDestinationArgs)
            }
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    @CallSuper
    protected open fun onCreateNavHostController(navHostController: NavHostController) {
        onCreateNavController(navHostController)
    }

    @CallSuper
    protected open fun onCreateNavController(navController: NavController) {
        navController.navigatorProvider +=
            DialogFragmentNavigator(requireContext(), childFragmentManager)
        navController.navigatorProvider.addNavigator(createFragmentNavigator())
    }

    @CallSuper
    public override fun onPrimaryNavigationFragmentChanged(isPrimaryNavigationFragment: Boolean) {
        if (navHostController != null) {
            navHostController?.enableOnBackPressed(isPrimaryNavigationFragment)
        } else {
            isPrimaryBeforeOnCreate = isPrimaryNavigationFragment
        }
    }

    protected open fun createFragmentNavigator(): Navigator<out FragmentNavigator.Destination> {
        return FragmentNavigator(requireContext(), childFragmentManager, containerId)
    }

    public override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val containerView = FragmentContainerView(inflater.context)
        // When added via XML, this has no effect (since this FragmentContainerView is given the ID
        // automatically), but this ensures that the View exists as part of this Fragment's View
        // hierarchy in cases where the NavHostFragment is added programmatically as is required
        // for child fragment transactions
        containerView.id = containerId
        return containerView
    }

    private val containerId: Int
        get() {
            val id = id
            return if (id != 0 && id != View.NO_ID) {
                id
            } else R.id.nav_host_fragment_container
            // Fallback to using our own ID if this Fragment wasn't added via
            // add(containerViewId, Fragment)
        }

    public override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        check(view is ViewGroup) { "created host view $view is not a ViewGroup" }
        Navigation.setViewNavController(view, navHostController)

        if (view.getParent() != null) {
            viewParent = view.getParent() as View
            if (viewParent!!.id == id) {
                Navigation.setViewNavController(viewParent!!, navHostController)
            }
        }
    }

    @CallSuper
    public override fun onInflate(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) {
        super.onInflate(context, attrs, savedInstanceState)
        context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            androidx.navigation.R.styleable.NavHost
        ).use { navHost ->
            val graphId = navHost.getResourceId(
                androidx.navigation.R.styleable.NavHost_navGraph, 0
            )
            if (graphId != 0) {
                this.graphId = graphId
            }
        }
        context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.NavHostFragment).use { array ->
            val defaultHost = array.getBoolean(R.styleable.NavHostFragment_defaultNavHost, false)
            if (defaultHost) {
                defaultNavHost = true
            }
        }
    }

    @CallSuper
    public override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        val navState = navHostController!!.saveState()
        if (navState != null) {
            outState.putBundle(KEY_NAV_CONTROLLER_STATE, navState)
        }
        if (defaultNavHost) {
            outState.putBoolean(KEY_DEFAULT_NAV_HOST, true)
        }
        if (graphId != 0) {
            outState.putInt(KEY_GRAPH_ID, graphId)
        }
    }

    public override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        viewParent?.let { view ->
            if (Navigation.findNavController(view) === navHostController) {
                Navigation.setViewNavController(view, null)
            }
        }
        viewParent = null
    }

    public companion object {
        /**
         * @hide
         */
        @RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP)
        public const val KEY_GRAPH_ID: String = "android-support-nav:fragment:graphId"

        /**
         * @hide
         */
        @RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP)
        public const val KEY_START_DESTINATION_ARGS: String =
            "android-support-nav:fragment:startDestinationArgs"
        private const val KEY_NAV_CONTROLLER_STATE =
            "android-support-nav:fragment:navControllerState"
        private const val KEY_DEFAULT_NAV_HOST = "android-support-nav:fragment:defaultHost"

        @JvmStatic
        public fun findNavController(fragment: Fragment): NavController {
            var findFragment: Fragment? = fragment
            while (findFragment != null) {
                if (findFragment is NavHostFragment) {
                    return findFragment.navHostController as NavController
                }
                val primaryNavFragment = findFragment.parentFragmentManager
                    .primaryNavigationFragment
                if (primaryNavFragment is NavHostFragment) {
                    return primaryNavFragment.navHostController as NavController
                }
                findFragment = findFragment.parentFragment
            }

            // Try looking for one associated with the view instead, if applicable
            val view = fragment.view
            if (view != null) {
                return Navigation.findNavController(view)
            }

            // For DialogFragments, look at the dialog's decor view
            val dialogDecorView = (fragment as? DialogFragment)?.dialog?.window?.decorView
            if (dialogDecorView != null) {
                return Navigation.findNavController(dialogDecorView)
            }
            throw IllegalStateException("Fragment $fragment does not have a navigationComponent.NavController set")
        }

        @JvmOverloads
        @JvmStatic
        public fun create(
            @NavigationRes graphResId: Int,
            startDestinationArgs: Bundle? = null
        ): NavHostFragment {
            var b: Bundle? = null
            if (graphResId != 0) {
                b = Bundle()
                b.putInt(KEY_GRAPH_ID, graphResId)
            }
            if (startDestinationArgs != null) {
                if (b == null) {
                    b = Bundle()
                }
                b.putBundle(KEY_START_DESTINATION_ARGS, startDestinationArgs)
            }
            val result = NavHostFragment()
            if (b != null) {
                result.arguments = b
            }
            return result
        }
    }
}


What is com.usmh.libraries.navigationcomponent.NavHostFragment?

@ianhanniballake hi already add the code of NavHostFragment

Does your problem go away if you switch to the default NavHostFragment? Everything that is doing is unnecessary.

Thanks a lot! You're absolutely right, switching to the default NavHostFragment was the way to go. It works perfectly.

Your ActivityMain.xml file appears to be using com.usmh.libraries.navigationcomponent.NavHostFragment. From the code you've posted, that custom NavHostFragment is not needed and you should instead switch back to the regular NavHostFragment provided by the Navigation library.
